# Where is my default password for DB2 that I made as a service on IBM Cloud?

Tags: api, db2, cloud

I made a DB2 Service on IBM Cloud. But, where is my password? I have never seen it, never made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decision: Go to "Service Credentials" -> write a valid JSON object in the window titled as "Add Inline Configuration Parameters (Optional)" like this one: {"text": "text"} -> push "Add" the button -> click on "View credentials -> do take a note about a key named "password" -> That's it is!